# Get some marker's position in vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, augmented-reality, marker, vuforia

I use vuforia with Unity.
A block appears when the AR marker is successfully read by the camera.
Successful reading of multiple markers．
I want to acquire the coordinates of the marker when recognizing the first marker．
I want to acquire the coordinates of each marker when recognizing multiple markers.
I want to do later processing with the image read by AR.

Comment: Please post code. What have you attempted? What isn't working?
Also, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates are simply the transform coordinates. However these marker coordinates are in relation to each other and the AR camera. There are 3 options to set as the world reference, in which everything else is calculated from and they're described here: [FIRST_TARGET, SPECIFIC_TARGET, and CAMERA](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/what-world-center-mode#comment-47076).